# Regex, how to detect value in double curly braces?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Sorry i can't speak english :(

I write Supplant I have a regex

```
({{([']).*\2}})
```

needs regex to detect what is in a rectangle

[image]

I need it rigidly between **{{'** - **'}}** because  there can be any character between the quotation marks (e.g. one **{** )

best to use it **\1** because regex is more longer

Thanks for the help. Regards

Comment: Do not fundamentally change the question after you have received answers. If you have additional questions, submit a new question.

Answer (score 2):

This can work for you:

```
/\{\{'((?:(?!\{\{').)*?)'\}\}/g
```

- `\{\{'` - start by matching `{{'`.
- `(` ... `)` - if you're writing a template engine you probably care about what's inside the curly braces and quotes. This captures the string inside the quotes so you'll be able to use it.
- `(?:` ... `)` - a non-captureing group (the value here will not be used).
- `(?!\{\{').` - match anything, except if we're seeing another `{{'`.
- `(?!\{\{').)*?` - `*?` is a lazy match, so we'll stop at the first `'}}`
- and finally, the closing `'}}`

as code it will looks something like this - I included a function to set the replaced value, because typically that's what you'd do in a template engine:

```js
let s = "n {{'a{123456789}'}} n {{\"a{123456789}\"}} n {{'a{1234{{'a{12345{{'a{123456789}'}}6789}'}}56789}'}} ";
s = s.replace(/\{\{'((?:(?!\{\{').)*?)'\}\}/g, (wholeMatch, capturedKey) => {
  console.log('captured key:', capturedKey);
  return "REPLACED " + capturedKey;
});
console.log(s);
```

if you want to support double quotes it becomes a bit more complicated:

```
s = s.replace(/\{\{(["'])((?:(?!\{\{["']).)*?)\1\}\}/g, 
              (wholeMatch, quote, capturedKey) => { ... }
);
```

Comment: In the negative look ahead, I think you should use `\1`, not `["']`.

Comment: @PoulBak - that's intentional - if we're allowed to use different quotes we can have blocks with different quotes nested within each other. we want the innermost one.

Comment: Ah, I see the point now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:`/(?<={{')(?!.+?{{)[^']+/gm`

This basically looks for the `{{'` which doesn't have any other `{{` in front of it then, matches everything till the first `'`.

Test here: https://regex101.com/r/rw6kkP/2

```js
var myString = `{{'a{content 1}a'}}
{{'a{every{{'a{everysign}a'}}sign}a'}}
{{'a{every{{'a{every{{'a{inside content}a'}}sign}a'}}sign}a'}} `;

var myRegexp = /(?<={{')(?!.+?{{)[^']+/gm;

console.log(myString.match(myRegexp))
// [ "a{content 1}a", "a{everysign}a", "a{inside content}a" ]
```